# Передача кириллицы через HTTP

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

Сервер отвечает на GET-запрос JSON-объектом в котором есть поля состоящие из кириллических символов:

{"model": "�����Ũ��","numOfBat": "2","numOfSrc": "7","numOfInv": "5","src1Tm" : "711 61 46 21 0x0b","src2Tm" : "712 62 47 22 0x0c","src3Tm" : "713 63 48 23 0x0d","src4Tm" : "714 64 49 24 0x0e","src5Tm" : "715 65 50 25 0x0f","end" : "end"}

Реализация сервера такова (микроконтроллер) что я не могу влезть в формирование ответа и поменять там заголовки. Я могу только отдать ему объект на передачу, все остальное от меня скрыто. Я вижу что в HTTP-ответе сервера кириллические символы заменяются на байты со значениями в интервале 0xc0 - 0xfe, 0xa8, 0xb8. Но при приеме в клиенте всё превращаются в (как я понимаю) Unicode и все эти байты превращаются в двухбайтное 65533. Как можно победить эту проблему и получить в руки на стороне клиента правдивые значения этих байт для дальнейшего перекодирования в кириллицу?

Comment: Используйте одну и ту же кодировку на стороне сервера и клиента и будет все нормально.

Comment: Судя по всему, сервер кодирует в cp855_DOSCyrillic  https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/PC/CP855.TXT

Comment: `я не могу влезть в формирование ответа и поменять там заголовки`. Напишите свой прокси-скрипт, где разрулите все как вам надо. Хоть на PHP, хоть на JS, да на чем угодно.

Comment: Судя по всему, сервер кодирует в cp855_DOSCyrillic - не совпадает

Comment: Напишите свой прокси-скрипт, где разрулите все как вам надо. Хоть на PHP, хоть на JS, да на чем угодно    - можно подробнее? что вы имеете ввиду? У меня появилась мысль при отправке заменять кириллический символ на латинский с управляющим префиксом а на стороне клиента перекодировать используя этот префикс обратно в кириллицу. Вы о таком подходе?

Comment: @Павел, пожалуйста, упоминайте участников через `@`, иначе не приходят комменты. По поводу прокси скрипта: знаете что такое проксирование? Это передача из одного в другое, через посредника. У вас такой путь: сервер с битой кодировкой => клиент. Будет такой: сервер с битой кодировкой => скриптик, который исправляет кодировку => клиент. Скриптик можно написать на любом языке и подрубить через веб-сервер. Получится нечто вроде "поиска и замены" на уровне HTTP

Comment: `поменять там заголовки` если дело только в заголовках, скприпт можно вообще не писать, а сделать прокси на Nginx, он умеет менять заголовки. Вообще я не понял, где проблема - на сервере, или на клиете. Дело только в заголовках или не только в них. Вытащите сырые данные из ответа и вставьте их в вопрос. Через curl, например